# Como cambiar el logotipo java de un Jframe en netbeans?

Tags: java-swing, netbeans-8.2, jframe

Quiero cambiar el logotipo java el cual aparece en la parte superior izquierda de la ventana JFrame . Yo uso el siguiente código en el constructor del Main:

```
Image ico=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("img/holger2.jpg"));

This.setIconImage(ico);
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto:

```
//crea un ImageIcon y define la ruta de tu imagen
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("turuta");
//define el icon a tu JFrame
tuFrame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

Espero y te sirva, saludos.

Comment: por favor añade una explicación, no se trata de solo poner código